# How to call a function when a Modal View Controller has been dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, function, modalviewcontroller

I currently have a modal view controller that I am using to sign in. Once the sign in is completed the modal dismisses. I am having trouble getting a func to run on the original view controller once the modal is dismissed.

I call the modal through a segue that is connected to a button on the main view controller. The func I want to run is already in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear where it works when the view controller is originally loaded and appears.

I am trying to figure out how to get it to run the func again once returned to the view dater the modal is dismissed.

Original View Controller:

```
class SignInView: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    checkUser()

}
```

Modal View Controller:

```
@IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if username.text == "" && password.text == "" {
        displayAlert("Error", message: "Please Enter an Username and Password")
    }

    if username.text == "" {
        displayAlert("Error", message: "Please Enter an Username")
    }

    if password.text == "" {
        displayAlert("Error", message: "Please Enter a Password")
    }

    self.emailLogin()

}

func emailLogin() {

    guard let username = username.text, let password = password.text else {
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Login Error")
            self.displayAlert("Failed to Login", message: "Username or Password is Inccrrect")
            return
        } else {

        print("Successfully Signed In")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: Change

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    theSignInView.callTheMethod()
}
```

The protocol/delegate pattern is often used to facilitate this approach.

Comment: I get the error 'Instance member 'checkUser' cannot be used on type 'SignInView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is called once when the vc is first initated , `viewWillappear,viewDidAppear` are called when you dismiss a model say with `overCurrentContext` / pop from navigationController

If the above isn't your case then you need a delegate inside `prepareForSegue`

```
let des = segue.destination as! ModalVC
des.delegate = self
```

---

```
class ModelVC://
  weak var delegate:MainVC?
}
```

Then before the dismiss use

```
delegate?.checkUser()
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also when you use `viewWillAppear` don't forget `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   checkUser() 
}
```

Comment: add this property to it `weak var delegate:MainVC?`